LazyVGrid inside ScrollView on macOS Sonoma performance
We have a simple SwiftUI app for macOS. Nothing fancy, just LazyVGrid with numbers inside ScrollView. And we run it on a MacBook Pro M2 Max 16' fullscreen. I can hit about 50FPS. Scrolling is not smooth. How can I get 120FPS on 120Hz Pro motion display?
Here is the code:
struct GridTest: View {
    @State var data = (1...30000).map { "\($0)" }

    //doesn't matter if this is adaptive or fixed..it is still slow
    //there is no way to hit 120Hz on mac?
    let columns = [GridItem(.fixed(90)), 
                   GridItem(.fixed(90)),
                   GridItem(.fixed(90)),
                   GridItem(.fixed(90)),
                   GridItem(.fixed(90)),
                   GridItem(.fixed(90)),
                   GridItem(.fixed(90)),
                   GridItem(.fixed(90)),
                   GridItem(.fixed(90)),
                   GridItem(.fixed(90)),
                   GridItem(.fixed(90)),
                   GridItem(.fixed(90)),
                   GridItem(.fixed(90)),
                   GridItem(.fixed(90)),
                   GridItem(.fixed(90))
    ]

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
                ForEach(data, id: \.self)  {item in
                    Text(item).frame(width: 100, height: 30)
                }
            }.frame(width: 1700)
        }
    }
}//GridTest  

FPS measured with Quartz Debug. Can be downloaded from Apple web in more section, Additional_Tools_for_Xcode_15.

Would there be a benefit in displaying this static view in 120 fps?

Yes, user experience. With real data, this is just huge table that can have up to 100k rows. If scrolling such table feels slow overall user experience is bad. Imagine Apple Numbers app, or MS Excel app. Scrolling the table must be fast. In this case we are not making another excel but we need to display tables where row have 20+ columns, and there are many rows. Content itself is not static, in the end user can edit each cell.

Scroll speed is limited by the graphical refresh rate?

It seems that limiting factor is text layout. Not text drawing, but text layout.

yes, overall redering is capped at display refresh rate. On Macbook Pro with Promotion display it is 120Hz. Airs have 60fps. There is huge difference between NSCollectionView and LazyVGrid in performance.

Considering you load 30,000 items into a single array right away when your view initializes, 50 fps is pretty good. Running it locally it seems buttery smooth to me. Regardless, this isn't a SwiftUI specific issue -- you need to do some work to make your loading system efficient (e.g. batch loading, publish results to the view from a view model, etc.). You mention MS Excel and Numbers which -- you may have noticed -- do not load 30,000 cells at once. In Excel for example, if you scroll fast enough on a large spreadsheet, you'll see it load in rows as you scroll.

I have tested this code with 30_000_000 items and scrolled to about 500_000 manually with no visual issues. Of course it consumes a lot of memory. Do you need more items or what is the true issue?

Number of items at load time isn't the issue. It loads in less than 5ms. yeah, computes are fast nowadays, M2 Max is really fast. I did profiling with instruments. Most of the time is spent on layout. So it would be somehow beneficial to speed up the layout, but I have no idea how. I made same view with NSCollectionView from AppKit. Guess what, it works much faster. Scrolling performance is almost flawless. So what I want is the same performance with SwiftUI. Is it too much to ask?

Why is this happening?
It seems you have confused the term lazy with the term reusable (also known as recyclable).
Lazy means it won't be initialized at the assignment point. Instead, it will be initialized at the first call. So, for example, using a range of 1...30_000_000 with a LazyVGrid, will NOT immediately take up 8GB of your RAM, but it definitely WILL take it all when you call all of them gradually, like by scrolling to the end.
But Recycling, on the other hand, means creating a limited number of objects and using them again and again instead of having a huge number of objects.

How can I improve the performance?
You should use the lazy method when you don't need all items instantly and use Recycling when the elements can be reusable.
In your case (I have bumped the numbers to make it extreme), the following line has a heavy impact and takes around 500MB memory right at the point:
@State var data = (1...30_000_000).map { "\($0)" } //  Using `map` will cause all 30,000 items to be created instantly!

It can be lazy since we don't need them all at once, like:
@State var data = (1...30_000_000).lazy.map { "\($0)" } //  Using `lazy.map` will postpone the map operation of each individual element

And you can use a View that recycles its content like the native SwiftUI List or a wrapped counter part from the AppKit a UIKit like CollectionView which is totally fine and standard to use and has a lot of built-in performance friendly APIs.
For example You can do the math an calculate how many items you need for each row and chunk the data into separate reusable rows:
struct GridTest: View {
    @State var data = (1...30_000_000).lazy.map(String.init) //  Using a lazy collection

    let columns = Array(repeating: GridItem(.fixed(90)), count: 15)
    var verticalCount: Int { columns.count }
    var chuckedRange: Range<Int> { 0..<data.count/verticalCount }

    var body: some View {
        List(chuckedRange, id: \.self) { rowNumber in //  Using a recycling View
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
                let range = (0..<verticalCount).map { $0 + rowNumber*verticalCount }
                ForEach(range, id: \.self) { index in
                    Text(data[ClosedRange<Int>.Index.inRange(index)])
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

You can also reduce the number of final rendering elements by making compositingGroups and even make them render offscreen by using drawingGroup modifier on each line but it should be benchmarked for the reliable results!
LazyVGrid(columns: columns) { ... }
    .compositingGroup()
    .drawingGroup()


Need more performant way?
SwiftUI is just a tool to make the basic UI tasks easy. If you have some advanced UI logic to implement (like showing millions of data in an infinite canvas), you should implement some more GPU friendly mechanism like using Canvas, Metal or etc. with prefetching, caching and even async loading mechanisms like what the AsyncDisplayKit used to do.
Also
There was a WWDC session (Unfortunately it was a long time ago and I don't remember the session number) that described how Apple implements the Photos App collection view with hundreds of Images to work at maximum FPS and even interactive by holding finger on small pixels to preview the image.
That can be good start if someone can mention the link.
I Hope this helps


 Premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming. Donald Knuth


I have tested almost everything: Just a LazyVGrid, this is probably worst about 40 to 50fps. List, much better 70-90fps, but falls down to 40fps with fast scrolling. Your take, 70-90fps with light scrolling, fall down to 40 with fast scrolling. Appkit CollectionView with Appkit cell, this one can hold 110fps consistently, with hosted SwiftUI cell 70-90fps, also bad with fast scrolling, fall down to 40fps. UIkit as catalist App with CollectionView + UIKit cell, 110+ fps, seems to be fastest option, when hosting swiftUI inside cell, 70-90 fps.

When swiftUI cell content is not updated, then it works as fast as in Appkit or UIKit, but that is not an option not to update cell content, right?. Option would be if "somehow" layout inside cell would be cheaper, but I am not sure how to do it to make it cheaper. In 4 weeks we have WWDC, I certainly have some question to Apple engineers ;)

You may want to prepare a benchmarking project with everything you have tested so we can checkout and see if we can find any way better. Also, please get back with your findings from Apple engineers ;)

Added one more test: scrollview is managed with swiftui, and visible part of table is drawn as NSView.draw(). You can get 120fps that way, but...strings must not end with ellipsis (...) or be wrapped to second line. If that happens performance goes to hell (70fps).

@JurajAntas Any updates on this? I also tried different things but nothing gets close to AppKit's performance. Also found LazyVStack performs usually faster than LazyVGrid, but they are for different purposes.

Had performance lab during WWDC, and have no good news. Answer is "It is not possible, sorry, use Appkit or UIKit if you need it". Well, that wasn't what I wanted to hear because we already have Appkit and UIKit implementation and we are transitioning to SwiftUI for all platforms. What you can get, in best case is 90-100fps. If that is good enough for you, go for it. List in SwiftUI is on MacOS implemented as NSTableView. Actually best way to check those hidden details is Instruments. Particularly in Xcode 16, with flame graph, is very good tool.

There are two big issues, or resource hogs depending on your use case: 1. if there is a lot of texts, CoreAnimation is using CoreText to render textures on main queue. This implementation is not able to draw screen full of text in 8.3ms. NSTableView with cell reusing also fails here. Only solution is to reduce table visible part on screen.


If your SwiftUI views are complex hierarchies, layout phase in SwiftUI is bottleneck, and there is nothing you can do. Once again, Instruments is your friend, Animation Hitches template or SwiftUI template. Hitches are broken, reported bug, so let's hope we get fix for it soon. And this is it.


@JurajAntas why don't you sum this all up in a blog post? People would love to read this!
